# What is the fastest way of searching for string in 2d array

Tags: python

I need to search for a string within the first column of a 2d array. The most obvious way is

```
for i in range (0, len(list)):
if list[i][0]==searchstring:
   list[i][4]=do_a_bunch_of_stuff
```

I need to know where "i" is so that i can do_a_bunch_of_stuff to the same row.
I need to loop through all of the rows in the 2d array

Speed is the main factor not pretty code. What is the fastest (CPU performance) way of doing this?

Comment: Is your array sorted in any fashion?

Comment: Does it need to be a 2D array? For example, are you willing/able to consider the use of other data structures (like dictionaries) that would offer faster performance?

Comment: Well i guess I can make the first column a tuple and loop through the tuple. Get the counter, and apply changes to the 2d array.....Is looping through a tuple faster?

Comment: If you had a small sample of the data you wanted to sort, it might help us to determine the best sorting/searching procedure. But in general, dictionaries (which associate a unique key with one or many values) let you find things much faster than by searching through a list.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a faster way to do this, you will always have to look compare the first element of each inner list of your search string.

The following may be marginally faster just because it avoids a couple of index lookups:

```
for x in lst:
    if x[0] == searchstring:
        x[4] = do_a_bunch_of_stuff
```

Comment: Also, it avoids the "range" call which creates a list (and it might be a large list).

Answer (score 0):

Since the column is unsorted, linear search is going to be the fastest you can hope for from search, as you'll need to check every element.

If this is a process you have to do repeatedly, you could create an index using a dictionary:

```
index = {}
for i in range (0, len(list)):
    index[list[i]] = index.get(list[i], list()) + [i]
```

You could then simply look up the indices of any string you need to search for using:

```
rows = index[some_string]
```

This comes at the cost of additional memory overhead since you're storing each unique value from column zero and a list of ints to boot.

If you don't need to keep the data in the 2D array format, you might consider restructuring it as a dictionary. You could use your search strings as keys mapping to a list of tuples, where each tuple holds the data from the other columns in that row.